# Git not detecting file rename, content is unchanged. Can't use git-mv

Tags: git, rename, mv

I have a committed repo, where the workflow is as follows:

Edit on remote machine1 which does not have git.

`~/project/files+folders`

After editing I rsync it to machine2, where it is merged with the repository.

```
~/project/.git
~/project/files+folders
```

On machine2 I then use git do add/commit the files. File renames are performed on machine1 via `mv`, and rsynced down to machine2. This is the reason why I can't use git-mv, because machine1 has no git and maybe it wouldn't even matter if it has because no commits are being made on machine1.

My issue is that a `git status` on machine2 shows that the renamed file is first deleted and then re-added, not renamed. The content is unchanged. Even when I rename it directly on machine2, it is also not recognized. Only when I use `git mv`.

This would mean that I need to rename all the files via `git mv` on machine2 and via `mv` on machine1, so that rsync continues to behave as expected (haven't tested this, but I assume it would not sync the renamed files since they are identical on both machines).

What is causing git to not detect the file rename via `mv`? Is there a flag which I can set so that this rename would get noticed?

One thing, I am assuming that no rename will get committed, because `git status` shows it as a `deleted` and `added` operation, while normally I see a `renamed` in `git status`.

A rename would look like this `mv module_stuff_information.py module_core.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add both changes (deletion and addition) to the index in order for git to recognize it as a rename. So `git add -A`, for example, should help.

Comment: Thanks. This was my issue. I had read about this but wasn't really sure about it. I did a test and it removed my worries. I was afraid to lose the history as I recently did on a couple of files which I stupidly edited and renamed at the same time.